# R: Unexpected behavior of str_extract from stringr on a string extracted from the web with rvest

Tags: r, string, rvest, stringr

I know this is an extremely weird example but it *is* reproducible:

I have a simple regex pattern to extract a person's height:

```
pattern <- "1\\.[0-9]{2} m"
```

Tested on a simple string it works:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract("1.75 m", pattern)
[1] "1.75 m"
```

However, it doesn't work on a string I scrape from Wikipedia, say to extract Linda Evangelista's height, using `html_text` from `rvest`:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_Evangelista"
text <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".infobox") %>%
  html_text()
text
[1] "Linda Evangelista\n\nEvangelista in August 2004\n\nBorn\n(1965-05-10) May 10, 1965 (age 52)St. Catharines, Ontario, Canada\nOccupation\nModel\nYears active\n1984–1998 (retired)\n2001–present\nSpouse(s)\nGérald Marie\n(m. 1987; div. 1993)\nChildren\n1\nModeling information\nHeight\n5 ft 9 in (1.75 m)[1]\nHair color\nBrown\nEye color\nBlue-green\nManager\nDNA Model Management (New York)Models 1 (London)\nView Management (Barcelona)\nPriscilla's Model Management (Sydney)\n\n"

str_extract(text, pattern)
[1] NA
```

Though, if you look closely, the `"1.75 m"` string is there.

To be sure, if I *manually* copy-paste the above string into a new variable, `str_extract` works as expected:

```
text_manual <- "Linda Evangelista\n\nEvangelista in August 2004\n\nBorn\n(1965-05-10) May 10, 1965 (age 52)St. Catharines, Ontario, Canada\nOccupation\nModel\nYears active\n1984–1998 (retired)\n2001–present\nSpouse(s)\nGérald Marie\n(m. 1987; div. 1993)\nChildren\n1\nModeling information\nHeight\n5 ft 9 in (1.75 m)[1]\nHair color\nBrown\nEye color\nBlue-green\nManager\nDNA Model Management (New York)Models 1 (London)\nView Management (Barcelona)\nPriscilla's Model Management (Sydney)\n\n"
str_extract(text_manual, pattern)
[1] "1.75 m"
```

Note both `text` variables are simple strings:

```
class(text)
[1] "character"
typeof(text)
[1] "character"
class(text_manual)
[1] "character"
typeof(text_manual)
[1] "character"
```

But are they identical? No:

```
text == text_manual
[1] FALSE
```

They seem to differ on the 83rd character:

```
str_sub(text, 1, 82) == str_sub(text_manual, 1, 82)
[1] TRUE
str_sub(text, 1, 83) == str_sub(text_manual, 1, 83)
[1] FALSE
```

But I have no idea why, they appear the same, that last character is a space in both:

```
str_sub(text, 1, 83)
[1] "Linda Evangelista\n\nEvangelista in August 2004\n\nBorn\n(1965-05-10) May 10, 1965 (age "
str_sub(text_manual, 1, 83)
[1] "Linda Evangelista\n\nEvangelista in August 2004\n\nBorn\n(1965-05-10) May 10, 1965 (age "
```

I thought about opening an issue in the `stringr` package on Github but I'm not sure whether it's a `stringr` or `rvest` issue.

Anyone might have any idea what's the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two string are different because they are encoded differently:

```
Encoding(text)
#> [1] "UTF-8"
Encoding(text_manual)
#> [1] "latin1"

utf8ToInt(str_sub(text, 83, 83))
#> [1] 160
utf8ToInt(str_sub(text_manual, 83, 83))
#> [1] 32

intToUtf8(utf8ToInt(str_sub(text, 83, 83)))
#> [1] "Â "
intToUtf8(utf8ToInt(str_sub(text_manual, 83, 83)))
#> [1] " "
```

(Note that your result for `Encoding(text_manual)` may change based on your locale)

To avoid this problem use `\s` in the `reg-exp` to match any whitespace character:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_Evangelista"
text <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes(".infobox") %>%
    html_text()

pattern <- "1\\.[0-9]{2}\\sm"

str_extract(text, pattern)
#> [1] "1.75 m"
```

Comment: You nailed it, Sir.